# Submitting forms using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, dom-events

I have been battling for the past two days with the evil `onbeforeunload` function in JavaScript. I have a function that warns the user when they are about to close a page.
However before the page close I would like to submit the form using JavaScript's `.submit()`.

This is my code:

```
function setPopUpWindow(submitForm){
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        if (submitForm == false ) {
        //alert("It worked");   --This code gets called so I know it works  
        document.getElementById("CancelScripting").submit();
        //return "Unsaved Data would be lost";
        }
        
    }
}
```

In my html I have two buttons, one is (supposed to) trigger the `.submit()` and the other will just ignore it.

```
<body>
 <form action=tett.html id="popUpForm" method=POST>
<script>setPopUpWindow();</script>
<input type="submit" id="submit_button" onclick="setPopUpWindow(true);">
<input class=b1 type=submit id="CancelScripting"  style="visibility:hidden"  value="CancelScripting" >
</body>
```

The `setPopWindow value for the second input is not defined so it would be false.
For some reason the submit is not working well.

------------------------Edit to my question-----------------------------------------------
I would like to submit the form even if the user leaves the page by closing the <kbd>X</kbd> button on their window. This is the reason why I have the hidden button... Looks like people misunderstood my question.

Comment: if there is no form then why input type submit is being used? this can be accomplished with input type button as well. Not function called `submit()` exist in javascript API.

Comment: There is a form. I just did not include it in my code paste. I figured people will assume it is a form. I will fix it to clarify

Comment: It would help if you would be more specific about what you expect to happen, and what is happening. It might also help if you posted a jsfiddle.

Comment: the form won't submit before the user leave.

Comment: have action attribute on the form instead of onclick event on submit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you can do is to ask the user if they really want to leave the page:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var submitForm = false;
        window.onbeforeunload = function () {
            if(submitForm == false){
                return 'You have an unfinished form ...';
            }
        }
        function setPopUpWindow(type){
            submitForm = true;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
   <form action="" method="post" name="SubmitForm" id="SubmitForm">
      <input type="submit" id="submit_button" onclick="setPopUpWindow(true);">
   </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Well I need the second link. I want to save the form even if the user presses the close button on the browser.

Comment: could you do it with the `onunload` method in javascript?

Comment: You cannot redirect the user to another page (even submit), it's all about the browser. And it's a security issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want to do is submit the form rather than the button by doing something like:

```
document.forms["formId"].submit();
```

where `formId` is the id of the form.

Also, I dont see anywhere in your code where your form is but your buttons should be inside of form tags.

For example, it should look like this:

```
<body>
<script>setPopUpWindow();</script>
<form id="formId" action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" id="submit_button" onclick="setPopUpWindow(true);">
    <input class=b1 type=submit id="CancelScripting"  style="visibility:hidden" value="CancelScripting" >
</form>
</body>
```